# Finding the position of the caret in a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to know the position of the caret in a TextBox so I can pop up a context menu near it. How do I find its placement (not character index)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Intellisense_popup.aspx) describing how to do what I need done. Turns out you can set both the PlacementTarget of the textbox *and* the PlacementRectangle from GetRectFromCharacterIndex and it will work.

Comment: If anyone wondering how to do the same with _RichTextBox_: `richTextBox.CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward)`

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750420.aspx).

Comment: I want to pop up the context menu near the caret as the user types (kind of like intellisense), not simply replace the default context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to get the character index of the carat and then turn that into a pixel coordinate by calling TextRenderer.MeasureText() on the text to the left of the carat.  This is obviously more complicated if your TextBox is multiline.  Is it?

Comment: It's single line, fortunately. I'll give the measuring text thing a shot.

Comment: TextRenderer.MeasureText() appears to be for WinForms, not WPF. I found the equivalent for WPF, but I'm having difficulty grabbing the position of the TextBox I need to calculate the anchor point for the context menu.

Comment: Oh, WPF.  Even though you used the WPF tag, you should probably also have that kind of information in the question.