# Obtaining caret position in TextBox

Tags: silverlight

How to get caret position (x, y) in the visible client zone in TextBox control? I need to add an auto complete feature to the text box.

I've found [solution for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053539/finding-the-position-of-the-caret-in-a-textbox), but it can't be applied in Silverlight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class AutoCompleteTextBox : TextBox
{
    public Point GetPositionFromCharacterIndex(int index)
    {
        if (TextWrapping == TextWrapping.Wrap) throw new NotSupportedException();

        var text = Text.Substring(0, index);

        int lastNewLineIndex = text.LastIndexOf('\r');

        var leftText = lastNewLineIndex != -1 ? text.Substring(lastNewLineIndex + 1) : text;

        var block = new TextBlock
                        {
                            FontFamily = FontFamily,
                            FontSize = FontSize,
                            FontStretch = FontStretch,
                            FontStyle = FontStyle,
                            FontWeight = FontWeight
                        };

        block.Text = text;
        double y = block.ActualHeight;

        block.Text = leftText;
        double x = block.ActualWidth;

        var scrollViewer = GetTemplateChild("ContentElement") as ScrollViewer;

        var point = scrollViewer != null
                        ? new Point(x - scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, y - scrollViewer.VerticalOffset)
                        : new Point(x, y);
        point.X += BorderThickness.Left + Padding.Left;
        point.Y += BorderThickness.Top + Padding.Top;

        return point;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [altso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922318/2016221), I'd like to mention that you actually need to call `.Measure()` and `.Arrange()` methods on the block for `.ActualHeight` and `.ActualWidth` to work, for example, like this (parameters may vary depending on your use case):

```
 block.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
 block.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, block.DesiredSize.Width, block.DesiredSize.Height));
 double y = block.ActualHeight;
```

This is **required** in WPF, and *advised* in Silverlight (including SL5). Otherwise you'll end up having 0 in `ActualHeight` in WPF and weird numbers in Silverlight (in my case, these were coordinates of a bounding box around *all* text).

---

As a separate solution, you could use [`FormattedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx) class to do the same trick.