# I need to fetch the co-ordinates of word from a multiline textbox in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, textbox

I have spent an entire day to implementent functionality like GetRectFromCharacterIndex() with no success. Microsoft has not implemented it for Silveright 4.

I need to fetch the co-ordinates (Start & End) of word of a multiline text box in Silverlight 4. It should be noted that the textbox is wrappable. I am not able to find it since a new line and a wrapped lines are two different thing. I am unable to to find the end of line for a wrapped line.

Is it possible to fetch the exact co-ordinates (It is not index of char in string/textbox) of word in a multiline textbox?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards

Sudhir Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `GetRectFromCharacterIndex` wasn't implemented in SL5 either.

The only way you can do this is to implement it manually.
To see example how it can be done, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921220/obtaining-caret-position-in-textbox). Be careful, though, since calculating such thing yourself is usually a performance killer.